# How to create insights or recommendations from SharePoint list using Syntex?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, azure-ai

How create recommendations or insights from dataset which resides in the SharePoint list. Is there any way to SharePoint Syntex would help in this Use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Syntex uses document understanding or forms processing to classify and extract metadata from documents and forms. If your SharePoint list is not a document library (only a list of data values) then Syntex does not apply.